# how to get the <script> code use regular expression from the page source?

Tags: javascript, regex

i want to get the script code ,except the outer reference script .
for example: i want to get the code of :

```
<script type="text/javascript">alert("test");</script>
```

from next s:

```
var s ='<script type="text/javascript" src="image/plupload/plupload.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="image/plupload/plupload.flash.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="image/plupload/plupload.html4.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="image/plupload/plupload.html5.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">alert("test");</script>'

p = /<(script)\s+((language=['"]?javascript['"]?)|(type=['"]?text\/javascript['"]?))?\s*\/?>.*(?:<\/\1>)?/gi;
var arr = new Array();
while(arr = p.exec(s)) 
alert(arr[1]+','+arr[1]+','+arr[2]);
```

but the regular expression is wrong  ,i can't get the right result

Comment: Regular expressions aren't going to let you reliably extract the contents of a script tag. The javascript language is a bit more complicated than can be tackled with a regex alone.

Comment: the `<center>` cannot hold, it is too late...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

but parsing out *non-nested* script tags from an arbitrary string with regular expressions and javascript is easy:

```
var input = '<div>random html in here</div><script type="text/javascript" src="image/plupload/plupload.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="image/plupload/plupload.flash.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="image/plupload/plupload.html4.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="image/plupload/plupload.html5.js"><div>random html in here</div></script><script type="text/javascript">alert("test");</script><div>random html in here</div>';
var pattern = /<script[^>]+?>.*?<\/script>/gi; //whole thing.
var matches = input.match(pattern);
var result = "";
for (var i in matches) result += "Match:" + matches[i] + "\n";
alert(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

[Never parse HTML with regex. The `<center>` cannot hold.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Either give your scripts a unique `id` and use `document.getElementById(MyId).textContent`, or just for-loop through them with `document.getElementsByTagName('script')[i].textContent`.